# unable to obtain all permission bits

Tags: go

On my shell, I have a file and I change the permissions of this file with `sudo chmod 4755 <file>`. Upon calling `lstat` on this file, I'm seeing correct information about its permissions, specifically that it has 4755 as its permission mode.

In my golang program, is there a reason why I'm not getting the correct permission mode bits? Could it be that I'm just formatting the result I get from FileInfo().Mode().Perm() incorrectly? Could it be that the upper 3 bits are "special"?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** The three upper bits ARE special and need to be accessed separately.

**Long Answer:** The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode) explains that the 9 (out of usually 12) least significant bits are considered the standard Unix permissions.

The documentation also defines the behavior of the `Perm()` function you are calling:

```
func (m FileMode) Perm() FileMode

Perm returns the Unix permission bits in m.
```

This means that perm is not defined to return any of the additional bits you are looking for.

Furthermore, the [source code](https://golang.org/src/os/types.go?s=1044:1064#L20) shows that the `Perm()` function is masking the value returned from `FileMode()` with `0777` causing the initial three bits to be disregarded.

The `ModeSetuid`, `ModeSetgid`, and `ModeSticky` bits (4, 2, and 1 respectively) must each be accessed individually as constants of the `FileMode` type. Do this by performing your own masks.

In order to determine whether the sticky bit is set, for example, do 
     `(FileInfo().Mode() & ModeSticky) != 0`. The same applies for `ModeSetuid` and `ModSetgid`.

Comment: Are you saying that these bits are masked? I tried doing something like (Perm() & ModeSticky), but I don't think this it he right way to go about it ...

Comment: I updated my answer with more specific instructions. Masking `Perm()` with anything won't help. The mode bits you're looking for have already been masked out of the value `Perm()` returns. You need to go access the variable further back, before the value is masked.

Comment: Great thanks! I just needed to tweak my implementation a bit.